# What does the following expression indicates?

Tags: matrices, vectors, signal-processing

In my research work I came across the following representation:

Let $B(m)$ be the transmitted symbols, $B(m)$ $\in${-1,1}, for $m=1,2,...,1000$.

My query is what does above statement indicates.

As per my understanding it is indicating that $B(m)$ have values either -1 or 1 and in total the $B$ will be a vector of dimension 1 \times 1000.

Please comment if my understanding is correct and please let me know the mistake if my understanding is wrong.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The statement does not involve vectors or matrices. It merely says that you have 1000 “transmitted symbols” $B(1),B(2),\ldots,B(1000)$ and the value of each $B(m)$ is either $-1$ or $1$. You may, of course, pack those 1000 symbols into a vector if you like, but that isn’t necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your detailed answer.